# Will a decreasing probability ever resolve favorably?

Tags: probability, infinity

Let's say I start off with a 50/50 chance at winning the lottery. But I lose.

Now my chance is only half as good, or 25%. I lose again.

Now the chance is 12.5%. Same result.

If this continues all the way down to very low numbers, will I EVER in an infinite amount of time win the lottery?

What if every time I received a ticket, I had a million times less chance of winning than I had before?

Comment: I don't understand your premise. How is the chance of winning the lottery connected to the outcome of a coin flip? (Which is 50/50 every time)

Comment: Are you assuming that your coin gets half as likely to come up heads each time? (A weird coin if that's the case!)

Comment: A very weird coin! But yes, the chance reduces likelihood each time. I took out the coin part to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first flip, you have a $\frac12$ chance of winning.

Assuming you lost (with probability $\frac12$) you win with probability $\frac14$, which gives you an additional $\frac18$ probability of winning, for a total of $\frac58$.

Assuming you lost again (probability $\frac38$) you get another shot at probability $\frac18$, for an additional $\frac3{64}$, for a total of $\frac{43}{64}$.

Continuing this on, the probability $p_k$ of having won after $k$ flips is given by
$$
p_0 = 0\qquad p_{n} = p_{n-1} + 2^{-n}(1-p_{n-1}).
$$
Notice that, except from the first step where you add exactly probability $\frac12$, at each step $k$ you add strictly *less* than $2^{-k}$. Because
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty 2^{-k} = 1,
$$
it is possible with positive probability for you to lose the lottery (although your chances are still pretty good).